# How to move an align block left such that the equations and tags fit on the page?

Tags: spacing, align, page, fit

How can I render a set of aligned equations with tags while ensuring that the equations are moved left enough so that the tags can fit on the page?  Preferably without manually setting a number of cm to adjust the align block by.

[Rendered equations.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4403528/3157)

```
\begin{align*}
\DeclareMathOperator{cov}{Cov}
\cov(Z) :&= \mathbb E\left[ (Z-\mathbb E[Z])(Z-\mathbb E[Z])^\top \right] \tag{definition} \\
\\ \\
\cov(XZ) &= \mathbb E\left[ (XZ-\mathbb E[XZ])(XZ-\mathbb E[XZ])^\top \right] \tag{by definition} \\
&= \mathbb E\left[ (XZ-X\mathbb E[Z])(XZ-X\mathbb E[Z])^\top \right] \tag{linearity of expectation} \\
&= \mathbb E\left[ X(Z-\mathbb E[Z])\left(X(Z-\mathbb E[Z])\right)^\top \right] \tag{factor} \\
&= \mathbb E\left[ X(Z-\mathbb E[Z])(Z-\mathbb E[Z])^\top X^\top \right] \tag{$(ab)^\top = b^\top a^\top$} \\
&= X \ \mathbb E\left[ (Z-\mathbb E[Z])(Z-\mathbb E[Z])^\top \right] X^\top\tag{linearity of expectation} \\
&= X \cov(Z) X^\top\tag{by definition} \\
\end{align*}
```

Comment: not clear why it's all so far to the right in that post, but mathjax rendering is off topic here, as it doesn't use TeX, can you show the problem with a latex document?

Comment: that said it looks like you can simply delete `\DeclareMathOperator{cov}{Cov}` I ried that in an unpublished edit and it seemed to work

Answer (score 2):

A comment up front: I will assume that `\mathbb E` denotes the expectations operator, a linear functional, and hence that round or square brackets placed around the argument of `\mathbb E` are just visual grouping devices which have no other significant notational significance. In particular, I will assume that \mathbb E[Z]`and`\mathbb E Z` denote the same thing. If this assumption is invalid, you should definitely ignore the first suggestion given in the following paragraph.

You can save an astonishing amount of horizontal padding by (a) replacing all instances of `[Z]` with just `Z`; (b) replacing all instances of `\left` and `\right` with `\bigl` and `\bigr`; and (c) using `\tag*` instead of `\tag` (which gets rid of the needless parenthetic enclosures).

I would also replace all instances of `\mathbb E` with `\E` and define the macro `\E` via `\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}`. This will give you typographically appropriate spacing both before and after `\mathbb{E}`. Indeed, if you don't pursue this route, you probably shouldn't follow suggestion (a) in the preceding paragraph either.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{showframe}  % draw framelines around textblock
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}} % expectations operator
\DeclareMathOperator{\cov}{Cov}      % covariance operator
\begin{document} 

\begin{align}
\cov(Z) &\coloneqq \E\bigl[ (Z-\E Z)(Z-\E Z)^\top \bigr] \tag*{definition} \\[0.75\baselineskip]
\cov(XZ) &= \E\bigl[ (XZ-\E[XZ])(XZ-\E[XZ])^\top \bigr] \tag*{by definition} \\
&= \E\bigl[ (XZ-X\E Z)(XZ-X\E Z)^\top \bigr] \tag*{linearity of expectation} \\
&= \E\bigl[ X(Z-\E Z)\bigl(X(Z-\E Z)\bigr){}^{\!\top} \bigr] \tag*{factor} \\
&= \E\bigl[ X(Z-\E Z)(Z-\E Z)^\top X^\top \bigr] \tag*{$(ab)^\top = b^\top a^\top$} \\
&= X \E\bigl[ (Z-\E Z)(Z-\E Z)^\top \bigr] X^\top\tag*{linearity of expectation} \\
&= X \cov(Z) X^\top\tag*{by definition} 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note, you can only do that if the `[` are not notationally significant eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Thanks. I've updated my answer to state explicitly that the suggestion to replace `\mathbb E[Z]` with `\E Z` -- where `\E` is defined via `\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}` -- would be inappropriate and therefore should be ignored if `\E` does *not* denote the expectations operator, a linear functional.